# Unity - Add Background Music on Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add some music in my game that can play in every scene, and if scenes change music doesn't start again and can be turn off on setting menu

can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: 1. Create a singelton gameobject in your initial scene.
2. Make it as 'Don't destroy on load'
3. Add Audio Source component
4. Manage this gameobject's component in your settings

Answer (score 9):

What have you tried so far? Show your code. There is a way to achieve what you want, that is by using `DontDestroyOnLoad` function. Create a gameObject, add `AudioSource` to it and then add the below script to that gameObject:

```
public class AudioPlayerManager: MonoBehaviour
{
      private static AudioPlayerManager instance = null;
      private AudioSource audio;

      private void Awake()
      {
          if (instance == null)
          { 
               instance = this;
               DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
               return;
          }
          if (instance == this) return; 
          Destroy(gameObject);
      }

      void Start()
      {
         audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
         audio.Play();
      }
}
```